# Is working in this context an adverb?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

Please read the following sentence:

> Editing requires a good working relationship with the writer and the design team.<

In this example, is “working” an adverb or an adjective?

Comment: Isn't 'working relationship' a compound noun?

Answer (score 0):

## A Very Interesting Idea

Here’s a very interesting idea for you: *working* is
**ɴᴇɪᴛʜᴇʀ** an adjective **ɴᴏʀ**
an adverb there!

Permit me to demonstrate.

Unlike verbs, adjectives can be modified by intensifiers like *truly,
pretty*, *awfully*, or *very*.  An interesting idea is an idea that’s
very interesting. So *interesting* is an adjective there.

That’s pretty interesting, don’t you think?

However, a working relationship is **ɴᴏᴛ** a relationship that’s
*very working.  And you cannot have a *very working relationship,
either. Those are both ungrammatical. So *working* is **ɴᴏᴛ** an
adjective here.

So what is it then?

Often *working* is a verb, as it is when you say that laboriously
working the land is a good way to earn a living.  In other cases
*working* can be a noun, such as in the laborious working of the land,
in the delicate inner workings of a wristwatch, or in the working
restrictions of work-release programs for prison inmates.

But that isn’t what’s happening here.

If your relationship almost works, then you have an almost working
relationship. Gee, that’s awfully verby, don’t you think?

What you have here is a present participle used attributively, which
makes it a particular kind of nonfinite verb.  Although present participles can be
used both attributively and predicatively, they cannot be modified by
*very* because they’re still much too unintensifiably verby for that.

So it’s definitely a present participle in your working relationship.
It is not an adverb, nor is it an adjective either. It’s a participle.

End of demonstration of that which was to be demonstrated. :)

Comment: He is truly king. She almost won; the almost victorious lady destroyed all knights.

Comment: So what I meant is that those intensifiers aren't necessarily perfect tests. I think *working* can be either a participle or a gerund in this case, depending on how the phrase originated: did it originate as a relationship that works (could be, but then there must be some casual metaphor at work)? Or as a relationship with respect to working (together)? The latter would seem more likely to me, so gerund. Then of course the gerund is used as a noun adjective, i.e. attributively. Cf. *running shoes*, *jumping contest*.

Comment: So what is key in choosing between participle and gerund is whether the noun is doing the action (the relationship is working), or the noun is related to the action in another way (a relationship related to working). Then the next transformation that happened could be from gerund or participle to plain adjective. Or even to fixed, unanalysable expression: just a working relationship.

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica Try that with *rather*: you can't have a rather king. :) But yes, you're right: I think you could also analyse *working* as a noun (well, a gerund at least) in a *working relationship* insofar as it is a relationship **for** working. A baby carriage isn't just a young version of a carriage. It's a carriage **for** babies, which means it’s an attributive noun there not an attributive adjective.

Comment: So syntactically speaking, a ***working** relationship* and a ***loving** relationship* are completely different kettles of fish and nother ballgames? (On account of the ***very** working / loving* difference.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes that's right. A working relationship is *for* working (together); it doesn't mean a relationship which *is* working (out (well)). I should probably explain this.

Comment: It seems to me the words ***functional, functioning*** are relevant here. Only the former can be modified as *a **very** functional relationship*, but semantically speaking they both seem to refer to the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Working - adjective added meaning to the noun relationship.
Good - adjective.

Good working relationship - can be considered as a noun.